# Get only the structure (row names & column names) of data set in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Consider a data frame with row names and column names:

```
> data <- data.frame(a=1:3,b=2:4,c=3:5,row.names=c("x","y","z"))
> data
  a b c
x 1 2 3
y 2 3 4
z 3 4 5
```

I just want to display the row names and column names of data like:

```
  a b c
x   
y   
z
```

I want a `data.frame` as output.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Do you want a data.frame as output?

Comment: Yes.I want data.frame as an output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you need

```
data[] <- ''
data
#  a b c
#x      
#y      
#z
```

If we need only the names, then `dimnames` is an option which return the row names and column names in a `list`.

```
 dimnames(data)
 #[[1]]
 #[1] "x" "y" "z"

 #[[2]]
 #[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

---

Or may be

```
m1 <- matrix("", ncol = ncol(data), nrow = nrow(data), 
        dimnames = list(rownames(data), colnames(data)) )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the column names in your dataset just use this

```
print(names(dataset_name))
```

For its structure,

```
str(dataset_name)
```